# Where to find SSH Login log files on centos

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I have shared a .pem file with few a developers and now something went wrong on the server. I would like to track logins in a log so that I can see who (IP) made changes and when (if even possible) what all change happened in that session.

I tried looking /var/logs/auth.log, I cannot find such file in my machine.

Few more details:

Hosted on AWS
Created and shared .pem file
CentOS - centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64
EC2 instance
I have not set flow log
Can someone help to track SSH login details ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

On CentOS login information is logged in `/var/log/secure`, not `/var/logs/auth.log`.

Answer (score 10):

In Centos 7 the SSH logs are located at "**/var/log/secure**"

If you want to monitoring in real time, you may use the tail command as shown below:

```
tail -f -n 50 /var/log/secure | grep sshd
```

Answer (score 7):

`lastlog(8)` will report the most recent information from the `/var/log/lastlog` facility, if you have `pam_lastlog(8)` configured.

`aulastlog(8)` will make a similar report, but from the audit logs in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. (Recommended, as `auditd(8)` records are harder to tamper with than `syslog(3)` records.)

`ausearch -c sshd` will search your audit logs for reports from the `sshd` process.

`last(8)` will search through `/var/log/wtmp` for the most recent logins. `lastb(8)` will show `bad login attempts`.

`/root/.bash_history` might contain some details, assuming the goober who fiddled with your system was incompetent enough to not remove it before logging out.

Make sure you check `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files for *all users* on the system, check `crontab`s to make sure no new ports are scheduled to be opened at some point in the future, etc.

Note that all logs stored on the local machine are suspect; the only logs you can realistically *trust* are forwarded to another machine that wasn't compromised. Perhaps it would be worth investigating centralized log handling via `rsyslog(8)` or `auditd(8)` remote machine handling.

You can also try:

```
grep sshd /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

And:

`last | grep [username]`

or

```
last | head
```

Comment: `.bash_history` only contains commands passed in a bash session. If you have SSH access, you can also access/manage all the files via SFTP unless this has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

A new project called SSHLog was recently released on GitHub that does this:
https://github.com/sshlog/agent/

This will report SSH login/failed attemps and also log all session activity to log files.

With regards to your question, none of the other answers will show you specifically what commands each developer ran and what output was recorded to their terminals.  After installing this tool, you'll find full terminal logs in /var/log/sshlog

Answer (score -1):

try this one

tail -500 /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd'

Comment: There is no such file , and I even /etc/syslog.conf also not there

Comment: try this commands :
journalctl -u sshd |tail -100
journalctl -u sshd
journalctl _COMM=sshd -f -n 100

Comment: Please edit your answer with the proper solution